# setInterval executing just once

Tags: setinterval

Please what is wrong with my simple code? It executes just once and stops:

```
 function confession(){
   document.write("i love coding!" + "<br />");
 }

 setInterval(confession, 1000);
```

Comment: Seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/01v9ya2L   Check your console for error messages, something else must be going on.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this, I get [this](http://i.imgur.com/d9r8uqt.gifv). While Google Chrome doesn't like the use of `document.write`, it runs your function multiple times just fine.

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel and David. It turns out that the problem was with the browser (Mozilla fire fox) which i was using to run the code. I have since installed Google Chrome and the code works perfectly now!